# jquery webcam plugin picture

Tags: jquery, webcam, jquery-webcam-plugin

i am trying to use the jquery webcam plugin and i believe i have placed every thing right but still i have a problem .
thought the #webcam div is working fine and show frames from the cam but on clicking capture no image is taken 
i get the following error on the chrome console :
Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'capture'

there are similar questions here but none seems to solve my problem
i have placed the callbacks too .

```
jQuery("#webcam").webcam({

    width: 320,
height: 240,
mode: "callback",
swffile: "../jcam/jscam_canvas_only.swf",

onTick: function(remain) {
},

onSave: function(data) {...
    }
},
onCapture: function () {....
},

debug: function (type, string) {
},
onLoad: function () {.......
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

$(function(){

```
jQuery("#webcam").webcam({

    width: 320,

    height: 240,

    mode: "callback",

    swffile: "../jcam/jscam_canvas_only.swf",

    onTick: function(remain) {
    },

    onSave: function(data) {...
        }
    },
    onCapture: function () {....
    },

    debug: function (type, string) {
    },
    onLoad: function () {.......
        }
    }
});
```

});